# Material Stepper setting selected index to dynamically added step

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-stepper

I use angular material stepper. I am trying to keep the current step while changing between horizontal stepper and vertical stepper. I'm using selectedIndex but it's not working.
Link to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/responsive-stepper-7tdmem) demo. Help is appreciated

```
this.myStepper.linear = false;
  this.myStepper.selectedIndex = index;
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.myStepper.linear = true;
  }, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update angular and angular material v12 or above(https://v12.material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview). There was an update and the orientation can be specified via input property.